# Schema.org for ranking of compared web sites for which an account is needed

Tags: schema.org

I have a website providing a ranking (based on reviews) of other websites that require a membership to access them (ex. Online tool requiring a monthly membership).

I have 2 question related to this:

- Should I use the `Product` or `WebSite` entity? At the moment I opted for `Product` since it has the `price` attribute and so on.
- How can I describe my ranking of website? I'm looking for a kind of ordered list of products (or websites if I have to change that).

Comment: 1) `Product` doesn’t have a price property. You probably mean `Offer`? 2) Do you show the reviews on your site? 3) For your ranking, do you only have a score/position?

Comment: 1) i meant offer indeed, 2) I show the reviews on other pages, my goal here is to have a page that display all offers and rank then, 3) position and score. I could use both or only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [`offers` property](http://schema.org/offers), you can directly offer the [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) (or [`WebApplication`](http://schema.org/WebApplication), which might be more appropriate in your case). No need for `Product`.

For the ranking, you have several options:

- With the [`review` property](http://schema.org/review) you can specify a [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review), which can have the [`reviewRating` property](http://schema.org/reviewRating) to specify a [`Rating`](http://schema.org/Rating). This allows you to provide specific scores (e.g., in the form of "1.27", "1.28", "2.04" …).
- If the rank is the average rating from all reviews, you can use the [`aggregateRating` property](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) to specify an [`AggregateRating`](http://schema.org/AggregateRating).
- With an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) you could specify for each entry a [`ListItem`](http://schema.org/ListItem) with the [`position` property](http://schema.org/position). This allows you to (implicitly) provide a ranking (i.e., in the form of "1", "2", "3", …).

You could also use both ways (`Rating`/`AggregateRating` and `ItemList`).

Make sure to apply the `review`/`aggregateRating` on the correct item: on the `Offer` if you are ranking the offers, on the `WebApplication` if you are ranking the apps.